# Did Star Trek VI ever have a soundtrack on vinyl?

Tags: star-trek, music, the-undiscovered-country

Was the soundtrack to *Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country* ever released on a vinyl record?

Comment: Not a complete answer...but a quick check on Discogs (which usually has all formats up for trade) suggests not...  https://www.discogs.com/sell/list?master_id=233608&ev=mb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes.

I found [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/RARE-LP-SOUNDTRACK-STAR-TREK-VI-THE-UNDISCOVERY-COUNTRY-CLIFF-EIDELMAN-1992-/111913567029?hash=item1a0e918335:g:6mIAAOSwk1JWeBL3) Vinyl LP for sale on eBay. It is listed as the Brazil Edition, so it is possible it wasn't released in the United States.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice! What are you planning to do with it (if you don't mind me asking)?

Comment: Well I plan to play it :) I got a decent turntable and I also have the sountracks for ST 1-5 on vinyl (including this one http://goo.gl/ttC7Iy), so this was the last one of the TOS movies that I was missing. Sadly, I don't think I'll be expanding the ST collection much since I think the newer movies didn't have vinyl releases.

Comment: I must say that compared to listening to these things on a CD, it really has somewhat better sound and definitely makes you feel better when you're handling the vinyl instead of the CD :) has an atmosphere

Comment: @Ondrej Well congrats on completing your Original Series collection.